# Changing the domain shown by Google Account Chooser

Tags: web-applications, firebase-authentication, angularfire2, google-oauth

In a web app we are using Firebase Auth to manage logins and (basic) account creation. When using the Google Login option with the user active with more than one Google account, the user is shown the Google Account Chooser to choose which of the accounts to use on our site. Its heading looks something like this:

> **Choose an account
>  to continue to *mydomain.com***

In my web app's case, instead of showing **mydomain.com**, it is showing **<firebase-project-id>.firebaseapp.com**.

What do I have to do to change is so that the account chooser popup shows **mydomain.com**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to customize that to: 
Choose an account to continue to: https://auth.example.com 
You would need to follow the following instructions:

- You would need to have your custom domain auth.example.com point to example.firebaseapp.com which is hosted by Firebase Hosting.
- You would then make sure you whitelist the following URL in the Firebase Console as an authorized domain (Authentication -> SIGN-IN METHOD->Authorized domains): auth.example.com
- You need to whitelist this page as the OAuth redirect URL for all your supported providers (Google, Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn): https://auth.example.com/__/auth/handler
- Finally, you need to substitute that domain as your `authDomain` in the JS client call:

  `var config = {
    apiKey: "...",
    authDomain: "auth.example.com",
    ...
  };`

Comment: When you say, "have your custom domain auth.example.com point to example.firebaseapp.com", does that mean a temporary redirect or some DNS A records?

Comment: DNS CNAME record.

Comment: You don't have to implement anything at `https://auth.example.com/__/auth/handler`. That page is provisioned for every project by Firebase Hosting to facilitate the OAuth handshake and secure transfer of result to your page.