# How to customize firebase email verification with personal domain?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I want to customize the firebase email verification with my personal domain name,
as right now it looks like this

https://project-00000.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?mode=%3Caction%3E&oobCode=%3Ccode%3E

and I want it to look like this

> https://example.com/__/auth/action?mode=%3Caction%3E&oobCode=%3Ccode%3E

How shall I proceed further?

I have already customised my domain, now I want to customise the URL link

Comment: See https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7000714?hl=en and https://medium.com/@arutkayb/firebase-auth-how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain-for-email-templates-1693999224be. You *might* also need this (depending on yoru setup): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532134/changing-the-domain-shown-by-google-account-chooser

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks I will definitely check them, your advice is always fruitful

Comment: this blog post was super helpful https://www.skies.dev/firebase-auth-domain . The main confusion I had here was from the `hosting` page of the firebase console. It always shows this misleading `Get started` wizard. But if you click `continue` all through the wizard and then when you get redirected to the actual hosting page, click "add domain" .